# Assets not loaded after deployment to Heroku due to 500 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a web application running on Heroku for several years without any problems.
Recently I upgraded to Rails 6.1 and on my development environment the CSS styling is working fine.
When I deploy to Heroku I don't see any errors, but after deployment there is no styling applied.
When I check, I see that all assets return a 500 error:

[image]

This is the error I see in the log:

```
Rack app error handling request { GET /assets/application-89108843b4f1bbe6098618a2216bf4f15c3be72b7076f9b443d058091a23386f.css }
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `match?' for #<ActionDispatch::FileHandler:0x000056220df0c280>>
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/heroku-deflater-0.6.3/lib/heroku-deflater/serve_zipped_assets.rb:31:in `call'
```

What could be the reason this is failing all of the sudden?
I tried to precompile the assets before deploying, but that makes no difference.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue https://github.com/romanbsd/heroku-deflater/issues/54

Comment: Yes, after removing the `heroku-deflator' gem it now works again

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Rails 6.1 and deploying on Heroku, you will not need to use gem 'heroku-deflater'

Remove it from Gemfile, more information can be found here
https://github.com/romanbsd/heroku-deflater/issues/54